# cURL timeouts from some sites, works perfectly on others

Tags: php, curl, nginx, timeout, varnish

I am trying to fetch the source code of a blog.

It does not matter if I try from PHP or from the command line. timeouts on both. Also tried `get_file_contents()` but same problem

### Problem

When I try this command:

```
curl http://blogg.se -m 5 --verbose
```

I get this:

```
* About to connect() to blogg.se port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 82.96.60.8... connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: blogg.se
> Accept: */*
>
* Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection #0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

But if I try with another url:

```
curl http://ip.nu -m 5 --verbose
```

It's working perfectly.

I was thinking I might be banned, but I have also tried using curl with a proxy and still time outs.

I can ping blogg.se with no problems.

I am also changing the user agent in the php-script.

This is my PHP

```
$url = "http://blogg.se/";

$curl = curl_init(); 

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Pragma: ";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,50);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$html = curl_exec($curl);
if (!$html) 
{
    echo "cURL error number:" .curl_errno($curl);
    echo "cURL error:" . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

echo $html;
```

On this server I am running a ubuntu with nginx, php-fpm and varnish

PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 - cURL Version 7.22.0

It is working (both urls from above) on a micro instance I have on amazon with pretty much the same configs - except versions.

PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 - cURL Version 7.21.6

Its also working from localhost on windows/apache with the same php script.

---

I have tried the cookiejar and cookiefile, but since I am not getting a response, I am not getting cookies either. also tried setting the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false.

Anything else I can try?

I also noticed that I can't ping my new server, but I can ping the amazon one.

So I disabled the ufw firewall, then I got responses by ping, but curl still did not work.

Comment: i have also checked in ubantu its working perfect

Comment: Working here too, only an error on line 27, but that isn't the problem. Version PHP 5.3.8 and 5.3.13

Answer (score 3):

You get a timeout because the remote HTTP server doesn't send back a response within your requested timeout period. It really is that simple. It actually doesn't even send a single byte within those 5 seconds, as is told by the error message.

You being able to ping it is completely irrelevant since ping is an ICMP message that is very different from a HTTP response from the site's web server.

Now, the question you would then of course ask is *why* doesn't the server respond to your request, and that's not easy to tell without knowing more. It could be as simple as that the server ignores you due to you having misbehaved previously, it could just be slow or it can be one of several other reasons...